# Setting a property on a list object in Python 2.7

Tags: python, list, properties, python-2.7

Consider this bit of Python code:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> l.foo = 'bar'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'foo'
>>> setattr(l, 'foo', 'bar')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

I understand why this doesn't work -- `list` has no `__dict__` hence it doesn't support attributes.

I'd like to know if there are recommended alternative list collection classes supporting custom properties, or, if there's a good Pythonic 'hack' available to add this to the standard `list` class.

Or is this a case where it's simpler to roll your own?

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> class Foo(list): pass
>>> l = Foo([1,2,3])
>>> l.foo = 'bar'
>>> l
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Yeah, that's about it.  Wrap it in a class.  Brain fade...  Thanks for the reminder...

Comment: @Eric what is `foo` with little caps in `l.foo = 'bar'`

Comment: @antitrust: You mean lowercase? That's just the arbitrary name of a property. The similarity to `Foo` is coincidental

Comment: ok, in this line you declare define the foo attribute for l and assign it value bar, right

Answer (score 0):

This is using `setattr` that you tried to use in the first place

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> lst = Foo(l)
>>> setattr(lst, 'foo', 'bar')
>>> lst.foo
'bar'
```